# Where does Xcode's core data graph goes?

Tags: xcode, core-data, wwdc

I thought there used to be a relationship graphs for Xcode at the right corner(As indicated by the orange rect). But it's missing for Xcode 14.

Does anyone knows where it goes? Or how could I get it back?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I noticed when creating a new Core Data project in Xcode 14 the xml file for the model still contains the xml tags that holds the position and size of the entities in the graph so maybe it's only the button that got lost in this beta version.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [release notes for Xcode 14b3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes), the diagram view has been removed:

[image: Fixed: Creating a Performance Report with the local Mac as the target device may fail with an error. (94643899) (FB10107014)]

Comment: Thank you! I just updated to Xcode Beta 3 and can confirm it's gone. Probrably forever gone. Hopefully they'll reintroduce those graphs in a high fidility version with modern design.

Comment: Good find, but that is bad news. I used it frequently to remind myself of the relationships between all the entities.

Comment: I’ve been working on a replacement CoreData graph viewer - if you'd be interested in being a beta tester, please let me know. Email address is in my profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/123632/ashley-mills?tab=profile

Comment: If anyone thought about trying this in lower Xcode versions, you cant. I tried on Xcode 13.4.1 and could not even open a project, issue: `xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode.`